# how to post array by store of sencha

Tags: arrays, extjs, load, store

I create one store and init it with some params with one array.when I execute the load function, the array parameter becomes a string '[object object]'

the code as follows:

store:

```
Ext.define('test.store.info',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config:{
        model:'test.model.info',
        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            url:'http://domain/path',
            actionMethods:'POST'
        }
    }
});
```

model:

```
Ext.define('test.model.info',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    config:{
        fields:[
            'code',
            'data'
        ]
    }
})
```

use in controller:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('info');
params = {
    t1:[{
        f1:'aa'
    },{
        f2:'bb'
    }],
    t2:'ddd'
}
console.log(params)
store.load({
    params:params
});
```

or I just use Ajax function instead load function , the result is the same.

```
  Ext.Ajax.request({
        url:'http://domain/path',
        method:'post',
        params:params,
    });
```

I check the xhr within network of browser , it is a string as follows:

```
t1:[object Object]
t1:[object Object]
t2:ddd
```

when I check the server log, it shows :

```
t1:'[object Object]'
t1:'[object Object]'
t2:'ddd'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution , thank you

## 1, just use jsonData instead params during Ajax, like follows:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: ajmd.util.version.getHost()+'/archimedes/update/selfInfo',
    method:'post',
    // params:params,
    jsonData:params
});
```

## 2, or just encode the data before send

```
params.t1 = Ext.encode(params.t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you name the parameter `"foo[]"`, then it will encode it as a POST array making it easy to consume on the server side. Note the `[]` at the end.

```
var companies = [1,2,3];
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '...',
            method: "post",
            params: {
                'companies[]': companies,
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("done");
            }
        });
```